# Affable Bean Java EJB Glassfish tutorial issues

Tags: java, glassfish, ejb

I have been following the affableBean tutorial from the NetBeans site located [here](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/intro.html) .

Code Repo [here](http://netbeans.org/projects/samples/sources/samples-source-code/show/samples/javaee/AffableBean) .

I have run into an issue where I am unable to submit a purchase order(checkout.jsp).
When I submit the form data, I receive an http 500 status and the following errors:

```
WARNING: EJB5184:A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB OrderManager, method: public java.util.Map session.OrderManager.getOrderDetails(int)
WARNING: javax.ejb.EJBException at controller.ControllerServlet.doPost(ControllerServlet.java:184)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at session.OrderManager.getOrderDetails(OrderManager.java:111)
```

> **Line 184 of ControllerServlet is:** Map orderMap =
>   orderManager.getOrderDetails(orderId);
>
> **Line 111 of OrderManager is**: Customer customer = order.getCustomer();

While running a debug session, it seems that the culprit is the line in OrderManger inside the *getOrderDetails()* method. From what I can tell,the line is supposed to populate the customer object with the orders’ customer.

Looking into where the .*getCustomer*() method originates it is from the CustomerOrder Entity class:

```
private Customer customer;    
...
public Customer getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }
```

Seems simple enough, it returns the Customer object. What is puzzling me is why I would receive a nullpointer exception, why is this object empty?

I believe it may be down to my entity class being incorrect, this in turn would mean my database that I forward engineered from a entity diagram would be incorrect, am I on the right path?

**Edit:**

Having removed the try catch block from the *placeOrder()* method within the *ordermanager* class
due to it modifying the return value to 0.

i have run into additional problems:

```
WARNING: EJB5184:A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB OrderManager, method: public int session.OrderManager.placeOrder(java.lang.String,....,cart.ShoppingCart)
WARNING: javax.ejb.EJBException
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Bean Validation constraint(s) violated while executing Automatic Bean Validation on callback event:'prePersist'.**

at session.OrderManager.addCustomer(OrderManager.java:58) (*em.persist()*)
    at session.OrderManager.placeOrder(OrderManager.java:42)   (*Customer customer = addCustomer()*)
```

I am currently reading up on how to iterate over the errors and find what constraint i am failing.

**Edit2:**

Debugging the *addCustomer* method i see the customer id is null, is this okay? i assume it is as the ID database field is set to auto-increment, still, seems odd to have an settable id field in the entity at all in that case.

**Edit3:**
Turns out the auto generated [NotNull] tags in my entity classes were causing bean validation to fail, removed the tags and it works fine.

Comment: You'd better create a new question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possible cause that I see for a NPE thrown there, is that `order` itself is a null object.

Since order is given by:

```
CustomerOrder order = customerOrderFacade.find(orderId);
```

my conclusion is that an order with that `orderId` is simply not present in the db.

Comment: You were right, I ran a debug session on the orderManager placeOrder() method and the 
try catch block was overwriting the getID value to 0
'
            return order.getId();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            context.setRollbackOnly();
            return 0;
        }
'

thank you.